# Winning strategy of a game

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

The following is a game on monomials.

> Let $M(X,Y)$ denote the set of all monomials in $X$ and $Y$, i.e.,
>   $$
> M(X,Y)=\{X^aY^b\mid(a,b)\in\mathbb{N}^2\}, 
> $$ where
>   $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,\dots\}$.
>
> Alice and Bob take turns to write down monomials from $M(X,Y)$ with
>   the following rules:
>
> (i) Alice moves first.
>
> (ii) $1$ is not allowed to be written down.
>
> (iii) The monomial that a player is about to write down can **NOT**
>   divide any monomial written down before or be divisible by any
>   monomial written down before.
>
> (iv) They are not allowed to 'pass'.
>
> (v) The player makes the last move wins.

Now the question is:

> If, by the end of each game, the loser pays \$$1$ to the winner for
>   each monomial written down (by either Alice or Bob), then does Alice
>   have a winning strategy to maximize the income in each game? What is
>   the guaranteed maximum income of Alice in each game?

I have noticed the following:

(i) Let $S\subset M(X,Y)$ and $S_{\min}$ be the set of minimal elements of $(S,\mid)$ (which is a poset). So if $S$ is the set of all the monomials written down in one game, then $S=S_{\min}$.

(ii) Alice in fact has a winning strategy: just write $XY$ down first then she will in $3$ moves in total.

Then I got stuck. I guess the guaranteed maximum income in each game depends on the first monomial $X^pY^q$ written down by Alice because if she plays $XY$ then the income is definitely \$$3$. So I guess if it has something to do with $p,q$.

Could anybody help me with this question? Or some clue?

### UPDATE

I think it might be too difficult to find out a winning strategy for Alice to maximize the money she can receive after each game. So here is another similar (but probably completely different) question:

> Suppose Alice is so clever that she has a winning strategy to
>   maximize the money she receives after each game, when possible. What
>   is the maximum amount of money that she is guaranteed to receive after
>   each game?

Answer (score 2):

Alice wins with any starting move of the form $X^pY^p$ by symmetry.  If Bob plays $X^aY^b$ Alice can respond with $X^bY^a$.  Alice loses with a starting move of $X^pY^{p+1}$ because Bob responds $X^{p+1}Y^p$ and wins by symmetry.  I haven't solved more disparate opening moves.

After Alice opens with $X^pY^p$, every subsequent move must be of the form $X^aY^b$ where either $a \lt p \lt b$ or $b \lt p \lt a$  There will be at most $2p+1$ total moves in the game because you use up the options below $p$.

Alice can win as much as she wants.  Her opening move is $X^pY^p$ with $p=2^r-1$.  I believe she wins at least $2r+1$.  As shown above, she could win as much as $2p+1$, but Bob can eliminate a lot of moves by moving to $X^{p+1}$.  Now no move with $Y^k, k \le p$ is available.  Alice can now move to $X^{(p-1)/2}Y^{2p}$.  There is symmetry between the intervals in available $X$ exponents $[0,(p-3)/2]$ and $[(p+1)/2,p-1]$, so Alice can play symmetrically to Bob and still guarantee a win.  Bob can eliminate one of the intervals, for example by playing $Y^{2p+1}$, but Alice can play the midpoint of the other interval and recreate the symmetry.  This is certainly not rigorous, but I believe it is plausible.

Comment: I have a question about the last paragraph. After B plays $X^{p+1}$, why is he threatening to win by $Y^{p+1}$? A could play $X^{p-2}Y^{p+2}$ if the value of $p$ allows and A could probably win I guess? For example, if $p=3$, then A could play, in the second move of hers, $XY^5$ and win the game in $5$ steps.

Comment: @TeddyFrei:  You are right.  I need to work on it

Comment: @TeddyFrei:  Please see the update.